# check_authorization causes custom devise controller to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan

**Background**

I have a simple app with devise and cancancan. Because I wanted to [add a little bit of custom logic to the signup process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63515713/5783745), I used [devise with customised controllers](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers), which simply means devise uses the users controller (rather than devise controllers) for all of the things devise does.

#### Problem

When I add `check_authorization` to the application controller, and `skip_authorization_check` to all of the user (devise) controllers, I still get the following error raised when the user tries to sign in or out:

[image]

#### Question

Does anyone know how to `skip_authorization_check` for these controllers? (I already have `skip_authorization_check` in every user (devise) controller, I thought that would do it, so I'm not sure what to try

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer 90% of the way through writing this question, so figured to post it in case it helps others in the future.

The answer is, simply [use the same method for skipping authorization checks on devise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277576/5783745) in the regular way (even if using customised devise controllers), that is, simply add this to the application_controller

```rb
check_authorization unless: :devise_controller?
```

Adding `skip_authorization_check` manually to each devise (or customised devise) controller does not seem necessary when using this approach.